# Не получается перенести сайт с сервера на локальный openServer. Перебрасывает на основной сайт, который на сервере. SOS

Tags: wordpress, сервер, редирект, домен

Сайт на Wordpress

программа text replacer прошлась по файлам сайта и нашла совпадение только в 2х файлах robots.txt и error.log, я искал по названию домена основного сайта, чтобы найти его и заменить на название домена локального сервера, но мне не помогло,

БД я поставил пустую. по идеи Wordpress должен начать установку, если не нашел в БД своих таблиц.

Но он просто перебрасывает на основной домен сайта и не получается запустить локальный сайт. Что делать? Есть идеи?

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Comment: Проверьте редирект в .htaccess еще

Comment: Проблема решилась сама по себе спустя 1-3дня. такое возможно? кто может объяснить мне почему так произошло к стати не в первый раз замечаю, что сайт после переноса редиректит на свой старый домен, а спустя некоторое время "становится нормальным" локалка отдельный сайт, а сервер отдельный сайт и никто никуда не перекидывает